# Is it bad form to include usernames in the ParseInstallation object?

Tags: javascript, java, android, parse-platform

I'm building an android application that uses Parse's push functionality to send messages between single users, and after a lot of finagling around with different solutions (without enabling Client Push because that's apparently a security risk) I settled on this:

```java
// com.myapp.Application.java
public void onCreate(){
    ...
    ParseInstallation i = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();

    i.put("username", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());
    i.saveInBackground();
    ...
}
```

Now, when I want to send a push to a single user, I call a Cloud Code function that does this:

```
// cloud/main.js
Parse.Cloud.define("pushMessage", function(request,response) {

  var from = request.user.getUsername();
  var to = request.params["receiver"];

  var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
  query.equalTo('username', to);

  Parse.Push.send({
    where: query,
    data: {
      alert: "message from " + from,
      // more data
    }
  }
}
```

This feels a bit like a hack, but it works. Is it bad form? I can't really wrap my head around the solutions I've seen so far, mostly because they're almost exclusively geared toward iOS and I can't read objective-C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I had to re-do this. I'll answer it just in case someone has the same problems.

The issue with including the username in the installation is that you *need to make sure* that you handle it correctly. The installation is, as the name implies, tied to the device instead of the user. This means that if your application supports several users, it's one extra step to handle on relog, otherwise users will get pushes not meant for them.

I forgot about doing some of that, and my code turned into sphagetti.

After digging around for a bit, I changed the method to instead subscribe to a channel named after the user's ObjectId, and simply sending pushes to that channel. I then unsubscribe on logout and resubscribe every time the application opens. That way, if you close the application you can still receive pushes. It works just as well, and requires less code.